# How to modify build output in esbuild `onEnd` callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, esbuild, esbuild-plugin

I am working on a plugin - https://github.com/mayank1513/esbuild-plugin-react18. It works well with `tsup` - [example](https://github.com/mayank1513/turborepo-template/).

However, I when I am trying to test, I am getting `outputFiles` as `undefined`. [Here](https://github.com/mayank1513/esbuild-plugin-react18/pull/7)'s the test setup. I can get legit value for `outputFiles` by setting `write:false` in `esbuild` options. However, that will not generate any build files.

How do I test this plugin and make it work with this esbuild setup?

I have also created [this issue](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/3408).